# Repelling Force of a Magnet

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am trying to invent something that utilizes magnets, but I've come across a dilemma. Two magnets need to repel each other with a strong force. So my question is: If a magnets holding force is 71lbs does that mean that it's repelling force is also 71lbs?

Comment: Roughly, but not quite and it would very much depend on the configuration of your magnets and the magnetic return path. You can do two things: 1) Use magnetic design software to design an optimal solution for your needs or 2) Get some magnets that you have in mind and do an experiment. Based on the results of that experiment you can then optimize the magnets.

Comment: CuriousOne, thank you for answering my question. What software would you recommend?

Comment: For starters you can try http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage. FEMM is pretty easy to use and it worked for me for the simple problems that I was using it for. The FEMM page has links to other free and commercial tools, too. Give one or several of them a spin and see what you can get out of it.

Comment: Al;so be careful doing experiments - you can destroy your fingers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0t8yDnyOaQ8

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I will be extra safe with the magnets. Though I don't plan on them being any bigger than a 1" cube. Nonetheless safety above all else.